# How to get the size of the screen size in a canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, screen-size

I am able to get the screen size in the normal activity but I need to get the screen size in a canvas view & manipulate in accordance with it.Any snippet on it will be helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i got widthPixels heightPixels use ing this.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();         
  int w = metrics.widthPixels;
  int h = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: This is the overall size of the screen however you will lose some of the height due to the notification bar and window title - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223264/how-can-i-get-the-actual-screen-height?lq=1