# How can I get the actual screen height?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the screen height, which is the

```
    DeviceScreenHeight - NavigationBarHeight - TitleBarHeight
```

The code below always give me a 752, but the real screen height is 800.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    mHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

And if I use onLayoutChange() to get the height of a vertically "match_parent" view, the height is 696. This is the value I need.

But I want to know how to get this value dynamically so I can get the proper "height" on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mWinMgr = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int displayHeight = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

where context is    Context instance.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but your code give the same result as my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
  RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
    root.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Rect rect = new Rect();
            Window win = getWindow();
            win.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
            int statusHeight = rect.top;
            int contentViewTop = win.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
          int   titleHeight = contentViewTop - statusHeight;

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int metricsheights=metrics.heightPixels-titleHeight-contentViewTop-statusHeight;
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124797/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-screen-size-in-a-canvas-in-android/9124906#9124906) code.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();         
int w = metrics.widthPixels;
int h = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what you wrote is the same as I did. What I want is device_height-title_hight-navigation_bar_height, in this case, it does not work.