# Display.getSize vs Dispaly.getWidth

Tags: android

I have a little issue here... I want to get the size of the display, which I can get either by calling the deprecated `Display.getWidth` / `.getHeight` or I can use `Display.getSize`...

But heres my problem... I don't want to use deprecated code, so that leaves me with `Display.getSize`... But that requires `API 13` and I would like my min-API to be 8....

What should I do? Is there another option?

```
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

width = size.x;
height = size.y;
```

vs

```
width = display.getWidth();
height = display.getHeight();
```

Comment: we want present screen width and height... see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124797/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-screen-size-in-a-canvas-in-android/9124906#9124906

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Display Metrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)

```
DisplayMetrics display = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int width = display.widthPixels;
        int height = display.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. works great! (will accept when SO lets me...)

Answer (score 0):

A more general SO question that explains how to use newer API levels and still remain compatible with older API levels is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959990/how-do-i-check-honeycomb-or-higher-is-running-and-accordingly-call-a-method-for).

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of checking the api version, but Eclipse wouldn't even let me run the code. So, I don't know if that would even work for me...

Comment: Sorry, I can't afford hardware that will run Eclipse :) I use IntelliJ.